# Wordpress adding in anchor elements when I save a page in html editor

Tags: html-editor

This [page](http://nicolaelvin.com/community/contacts/) I am editing in the html editor.  I pasted in my list from my text editor.  You'll notice that the second last list item is all a link, thats because wordpress has taken it upon itself to wrap the whole thing in an empty  tag!  Why is it doing this and more importantly, how do I stop it?

FYI here is the relevant ul

```
<ul class="company-details">
        <li>Target Health & Fitness</li>
        <li>7 Sheffield Road Holmfirth HD9 7BW</li>
        <li>01484 681000</li>           
        <li><a href="mailto:enquiry@target-leisure.com">enquiry@target-leisure.com</a></li>
    </ul>
```

inside that wordpress has added an anchor, if you inspect it using inspector or firebug.

I've added these filters thinking they'd work but they haven't

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); 
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: when I looked again at my code, there were the wrong quotes in - those curly ones and an anchor was closed wrongly - <a/>.  Always double check the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember which one, but there is probably a conflict with tone of your plugins. I had the same issue in the past.

Deactivate all of you plugins, then go through and reactivate them one by one.

Comment: When I re-enabled the visual editor and then saved my page it seems to sort it.  Thanks.

Comment: Nicola, make sure to go back through all your old questions and give the correct answers upvotes and/or checkmarks. If you do not accept answers on your questions, other users are less likely to assist you.